# Universal App VS2015 C++ How to convert String^ to float?

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx

I am using `Visual studio 2015` to build an app Universal by `C++`;
When I want to convert `Textbox->Text` to `float` type. I search google but don't have solve. I can't use `TryParse or Convert:: or float.parse`. 
Here is the using of my `Mainpage.cpp`

```
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
```

and I can't use `System::`. When I write it show a `syntax error`

Comment: You are writing pure native code, you cannot use .NET Framework namespaces or methods.  Use normal C++ conversion functions, like `_wtof(someString->Data)` or stod() if you prefer converting to wstring.

Comment: Thanks for reponse. I write this : float a = _wtof(textBox->Text->Data); and got a error C3867: 'Platform::String::Data': non-standard syntax; use App1 (my project name) '&' to create a pointer to member. How should I fix it?

Comment: `Data` is a method, so use `Data()`

Comment: Oh my mistake! Thank you @PeterTorr-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
String^ text = "3.14";

std::wstring textToConvert = std::wstring(text->Data());

float value = std::stof(textToConvert);
```